# serializing json over wire

Tags: encoding, f#

Which of the following approach is better when it comes to encoding and why?

I've written three approaches,

**Http POST request**

**Option A - ASCII**

```
let request = WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
request.Method <- "POST"
request.ContentType <- "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
use memoryStream = new MemoryStream() 
(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Article>)).WriteObject(memoryStream, schema) 

// option A
let str = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()) // using ASCII
let data : byte[] = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str); 

request.ContentLength <- (int64)data.Length
use requestStream = request.GetRequestStream() 
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
requestStream.Flush()
requestStream.Close()
```

**Option B - UTF-8**

```
let request = WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
request.Method <- "POST"
request.ContentType <- "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
use memoryStream = new MemoryStream() 
(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Article>)).WriteObject(memoryStream, schema) 

// option B
let s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()) // using UTF-8
let data : byte[] = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(d);

request.ContentLength <- (int64)data.Length
use requestStream = request.GetRequestStream() 
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
requestStream.Flush()
requestStream.Close()
```

**Option C- direct memory stream**

```
let request = WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
request.Method <- "POST"
request.ContentType <- "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
use memoryStream = new MemoryStream() 
(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Article>)).WriteObject(memoryStream, schema) 

// option C direct memory stream to array
let data : byte[] = memoryStream.ToArray() 

request.ContentLength <- (int64)data.Length
use requestStream = request.GetRequestStream() 
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
requestStream.Flush()
requestStream.Close()
```

Comment: The choice of encoding depends on how the data was serialized. For example, if the serializer uses ASCII, then so should deserializer

Comment: it's not clear what the api is using, I think `utf-8` is save, but what do you think about direct `memoryStream.ToArray()`, any complications with that?

Comment: This question is too vague to be answerable. What is the data type you're expecting to decode? If it's a binary blob, then the `byte[]` option is the best. If it's JSON as you mention in the title of the question but nowhere else, then you should use UTF-8 (and then I don't know why you'd want `let data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)` — do you need the bytes later?). There's not enough information in your question to be able to give a good answer.

Comment: I've a record in F# with fields and values, and I want to send it as JSON to the remote server, now which option to use? I'm making an API call so how'd you convert a record into json and send to the server using `DataContractJsonSerializer`?, what's the right? It's an http post request, hope this helps, please ask more if not clear.

Comment: Looks like you are doing it hard way. Have you considered FSharp.Data? http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html

Comment: Hi Alexandra, yes I know and used the library but I like the hard way :) I'm not sure why it's so difficult to choose from Option A, B and C to serialize an object, as a matter of fact all 3 works but wondering what's the right way, shall I do `memoryStream.ToArray() ` without going through encoding process or not?

Comment: hi guys, I've edited a bit, can you please review, is there a problem if I approach via either options? it's more a question for option C approach, is there any problem with that?